# Градиент, не зависящий от разрешения экрана

Tags: html, css3, html5, веб-программирование, вёрстка

У меня проблема с градиентом.
Нужно чтобы наложение желтого и красного оставалось одинаковым по размеру, но в зависимости от разрешения, градиент уезжает вверх, либо вниз.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.back {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4000px;
  background-color: red;
  background: linear-gradient(153deg,#fff 20%,red 20.05%,red 23%,#fff 41%,#fff 58.95%,green 58%);
}

.aim-block {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: yellow;
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<div class="back">
  <div class="aim-block">
  </div>
</div>
```

Можно ли как-то зафиксировать градиент, чтобы он не зависел от разрешения?
Хотелось бы так же, бэкграундом, без псевдоэлементов. Но, в любом случае, все варианты приветствую.

Comment: используйте vw или px вместо % в градиенте

Comment: да, не подумал об этом, спасибо